# BufferedReader not returning expected result when using ImageMagick

Tags: java, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So I'm using ImageMagick to resize an image. It does that and saves to the file system as output.png. However, it doesn't print out the bytes of the image. Am I just having a brain fart or am I missing the point in what ImageMagick is meant to do. Thanks.

```
String[] command = {"convert", "hello.png", "-resize", "1280x720", "output.png"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of ImageMagick to be, and why? You say "It doesn't print out the bytes of the image" - but surely those bytes should be in output.png. What do you see when you run this from a regular shell? Also note that you're redirecting the *error* stream, but not the *output* stream.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes through the shell no bytes are printed through console. Is there a way to to retrieve these bytes like I'm doing with the stream reader? Something to do with redirecting the output stream like you say???

Comment: But ImageMagick isn't writing the result to standard out - it's writing to `output.png`. Why not just load `output.png`? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. I don't know whether you can persuade ImageMagick to write the conversion result to stdout, but that part isn't a Java issue. Note that if you *could* do that, it would be inappropriate to use a `BufferedReader`, as that's for *text* data, and the PNG file is *binary* data.

Comment: Okay so with ImageMagick I would need to resize the image as I'm doing then load output.png, convert to a byte[], return to client.

Comment: Maybe - I don't know. You'd need to research whether there's any way of getting ImageMagick to write to stdout instead of a file, but that's not a Java issue. Once you've done that, you'll need to read it with an `InputStream`, *not* a `Reader`.